Get a list of users with UID > 14000 - string to int conversion
In my playbook I want to get a list of all local users with UI above 14000
I used ansible.builtin.slurp on /etc/passwd or ansible.builtin.getent but the real issue is the UID value that I get is string, not int so I can't filter properly and all results I get are empty, or complain because is not an integer.
- name: Get all users from /etc/passwd
  ansible.builtin.getent:
    database: passwd
  register: users_info

- name: Filter users with UID greater than 14000
  set_fact:
    filtered_users: >-
      {{
        users_info.ansible_facts.getent_passwd |
        dict2items |
        selectattr('value.1', 'int') |
        selectattr('value.1', >, 14000) |
        map(attribute='key') |
        list
      }}

I thought selectattr('value.1', 'int') would convert to int, but the result is always empty. (I do have some UID above 14000 in the dict)
Here the user dict that getent provides, all UID are quoted so they are string
root:
- x
- '0'
- '0'
- root
- /root
- /bin/bash
shutdown:
- x
- '6'
- '0'
- shutdown
- /sbin
- /sbin/shutdown
sshd:
- x
- '74'
- '74'
- Privilege-separated SSH
- /usr/share/empty.sshd
- /sbin/nologin

I run out of idea to try, except run some shell cmd which I would avoid.

I can see several problems with your filter chain:
filtered_users: >-
  {{
    users_info.ansible_facts.getent_passwd |
    dict2items |
    selectattr('value.1', 'int') |
    selectattr('value.1', >, 14000) |
    map(attribute='key') |
    list
  }}

First, there is no test named int, although there is a filter named integer. Unfortunately, this is a test, not a conversion filter, so since in all cases the value of value.1 is a string, this selectattr() filter will reject all of your entries, leading to an empty list. Everything after this point is irrelevant because there is nothing left to filter.
For example:
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    example:
      - val: '1'
      - val: '2'
      - val: '3'
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ example | selectattr('val', 'integer') }}"

Results in:
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": []
}

I think you'll find a solution using the json_query filter is simpler. For what you want, we could do this:
- name: Filter users with UID > 1000
  set_fact:
    filtered_users: >-
        {{
          users_info.ansible_facts.getent_passwd |
          dict2items |
          json_query('[?to_number(value[1]) > `1000`].key')
        }}

Here, we're using the to_number function to convert the string values into integers for comparison.
On my system, this produces:
ok: [localhost] => {
    "filtered_users": [
        "nobody"
    ]
}


Use community.general.jc to parse the file /etc/passwd. Declare the destination
  dest_dir: /tmp/ansible/fetch

and fetch the file
    - fetch:
        src: /etc/passwd
        dest: "{{ dest_dir }}"

Declare the path and parse the file
  passwd_path: "{{ dest_dir }}/{{ inventory_hostname }}/etc/passwd"
  my_users: "{{ lookup('file', passwd_path) | community.general.jc('passwd') }}"

gives (abridged)
  my_users:
  - comment: Charlie &
    gid: 0
    home: /root
    password: '*'
    shell: /bin/sh
    uid: 0
    username: root
  - comment: Bourne-again Superuser
    ...

The attributes uid and gid are integers. You can test it
    - debug:
        msg: |
          {{ my_users.0.username }}
          {{ my_users.0.uid }}
          {{ my_users.0.uid | type_debug }}

gives
  msg: |-
    root
    0
    int

Now, the selection works as expected
  filtered_users: "{{ my_users |
                      selectattr('uid', '>', 14000) |
                      map(attribute='username') }}"

gives
  filtered_users:
  - nobody




Example of a complete playbook for testing

- hosts: host_a

  vars:

    dest_dir: /tmp/ansible/fetch
    passwd_path: "{{ dest_dir }}/{{ inventory_hostname }}/etc/passwd"
    my_users: "{{ lookup('file', passwd_path) | community.general.jc('passwd') }}"
    filtered_users: "{{ my_users | selectattr('uid', '>', 14000) | map(attribute='username') }}"

  tasks:

    - fetch:
        src: /etc/passwd
        dest: "{{ dest_dir }}"

    - debug:
        var: my_users

    - debug:
        msg: |
          {{ my_users.0.username }}
          {{ my_users.0.uid }}
          {{ my_users.0.uid | type_debug }}

    - debug:
        var: filtered_users


Proposed scenario

Put the declarations into the group_vars
shell> cat group_vars/all.yml
dest_dir: /tmp/ansible/fetch
passwd_path: "{{ dest_dir }}/{{ inventory_hostname }}/etc/passwd"
my_users: "{{ lookup('file', passwd_path) | community.general.jc('passwd') }}"
uid_min: 0
uid_max: 65535
filtered_users_min: "{{ my_users | selectattr('uid', '>=', uid_min|int) | map(attribute='username') }}"
filtered_users_max: "{{ my_users | selectattr('uid', '<=', uid_max|int) | map(attribute='username') }}"
filtered_users: "{{ filtered_users_min | intersect(filtered_users_max) }}"

In the playbook, fetch the file and declare the interval. For example,
shell> cat playbook.yml
---
- hosts: host_a

  tasks:

    - fetch:
        src: /etc/passwd
        dest: "{{ dest_dir }}"

    - debug:
        var: filtered_users
      vars:
        uid_min: 14000



Thanks to @larsks' answer, I was able to modify my query to filter 14000-15000 UID as follows which is giving the expected result:
- name: Filter users 14k-15k range
  set_fact:
    filtered_users: >-
      {{
        users_info.ansible_facts.getent_passwd |
        dict2items |
        json_query('[?to_number(value[1]) > `14000` && to_number(value[1]) <= `15000`].key')
      }}

